# Writeraster: How to mantain layer names when writing raster data to a file

Tags: raster, r, stack, rasterstack

After I change the extension of my different raster layers in R, I want to save them in the same folder to, later on, binarize them all (with a for in loop I have in my code). Because I want all these binarized rasters to maintain the **name of the raster** they come from, I need to have the original name of the layer which I lost when I save them with writeRaster. When I write the raster data to a file, the names come with the default name "layer" instead of the original name. Here is an example:

`````
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

raster_test <- raster("landuse.tif")
newt_extent <- (456682, 525910, 4622042, 4705373)
raster_test <- setExtent(raster_test, new_extent, keepres=TRUE)
raster_test
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2778, 2308, 6411624  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 29.99458, 29.99658  (x, y)
extent     : 456682, 525910, 4622042, 4705373  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : landuse.tif 
names      : landuse
values     : 15, 89  (min, max)

names(raster_test)
[1] "landuse"

writeRaster(raster_test, "landuse_final.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
final_raster <- raster("landuse_final-tif")
final_raster
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2778, 2308, 6411624  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 29.99458, 29.99658  (x, y)
extent     : 456682, 525910, 4622042, 4705373  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : landuse.tif 
names      : layer
values     : 15, 89  (min, max)

names(final_raster)
[1] "layer" ```

## So, I would like to maintain "land_use" as a name of the layer. 

## I have tried different options with writeRaster (````bylayer= TRUE````, 
```suffix = names(x)```, ```full.names(TRUE)```, etc) but none of them with 
success. It should be a very simple answer but I didn't find it. If I 
maintain this layer name as the original when I binarize the raster I get 
the files with this name followed by a number which is exactly what I need.
`````

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `tif` file format doesn't keep the layer names. Use `names(rast) <- "layer_name"` to modify the layer names as you wish or use formats that keep the layer names as .grd`.

```r
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp
library(rgdal)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
f
#> [1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/raster/external/test.grd"
raster_test <- raster(f)
new_extent <- extent(raster_test) + c(10, -10, 10, -10) # c(456682, 525910, 4622042, 4705373)
raster_test <- setExtent(raster_test, new_extent, keepres=TRUE)
raster_test
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 114, 80, 9120  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 40, 40  (x, y)
#> extent     : 178410, 181610, 329410, 333970  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> source     : test.grd 
#> names      : test 
#> values     : 138.7071, 1736.058  (min, max)

names(raster_test)
#> [1] "test"

tmp_file<- paste0(tempfile(tmpdir = "."), ".tif")
tmp_file
#> [1] "./file2a5638fcce90.tif"
writeRaster(raster_test, tmp_file, overwrite=TRUE)
final_raster <- raster(tmp_file)
final_raster
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 114, 80, 9120  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 40, 40  (x, y)
#> extent     : 178410, 181610, 329410, 333970  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> source     : file2a5638fcce90.tif 
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 138.7071, 1736.058  (min, max)


names(final_raster)<- "my_layer_name"
names(final_raster)
#> [1] "my_layer_name"

# Or use the file name as layer name
files <- dir(pattern = "\\.tif$")
layer_name<- gsub("\\.tif$", "", files)
names(final_raster) <- layer_name
final_raster
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 114, 80, 9120  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 40, 40  (x, y)
#> extent     : 178410, 181610, 329410, 333970  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#> source     : file2a5638fcce90.tif 
#> names      : file2a5638fcce90 
#> values     : 138.7071, 1736.058  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `terra`-package. It is meant to replace the older and slower `raster` package. With Terra, I haven't had any difficulties saving the layer names.

````r
#' read the default elevation raster in from the terra package
r <- terra::rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package = "terra"))
r
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 90, 95, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : 5.741667, 6.533333, 49.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : elev.tif 
# name        : elevation 
# min value   :       141 
# max value   :       547 

#' define a new extent for the raster
new_ext <- ext(r) + c(1, -1, 1, -1)

#' apply the extent on raster `r`
r_shifted <- extend(r, new_ext)

#' change the layer name of the raster
set.names(r_shifted, 'Elevation')

r_shifted
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 210, 215, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : 4.741667, 6.533333, 48.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source(s)   : memory
# name        : Elevation 
# min value   :       141 
# max value   :       547 

#' write the rater to file using the terra-version of the `writeRaster` command
terra::writeRaster(r_shifted, 'new_elev_rast.tif', overwrite = T)

#' read it again and check its outputs 
r_disk <- rast('new_elev_rast.tif')
r_disk
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 210, 215, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : 4.741667, 6.533333, 48.44167, 50.19167  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : new_elev_rast.tif 
# name        : Elevation 
# min value   :       141 
# max value   :       547 ```
````